# GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/:userId 400 (Bad Request), Axios React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http, axios

I am working on a MERN stack and I am trying to display a single user's data on its own page. The route works on the server-side in Postman, I am able to get the user by Id. But on the client-side I get a 400 bad request when trying to get the user information with axios from that route. could their be a problem with any of my endpoints?

[image: What localhost shows in my console]

[image: Error in the console]

Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


import Navbar from '../layouts/navbar'
// import './userDashboard.css'
class userDashboard extends Component {

    state = {
        user: {}
    }

    getUser = () =>{
    const userId = this.props.match.params.userId
       axios.get('/api/users/' + userId ).then(res=>{
           const user = res.data;
           this.setState({
               user
           })
       }).catch((err)=> console.log(err))
    }

    


    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUser()
    }
    render() {

        const { name } = this.state.user 
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar />
        <h1 className="title-text">Hello { name }</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

userDashboard.propTypes = {
    // logoutUser: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  };
  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    auth: state.auth,
  });
  export default connect(mapStateToProps)(userDashboard);
```

controller

```
router.get("/:userId", (req, res) => {
      const { userId } = req.params;

        if(!userId){
           return res.status(400).json({message: "user id not found"})
        }

        if(!ObjectId.isValid(userId)){
           return res.status(400).json({ message: "userId not valid"})
        }

        User.findById(userId,(err, user) => {
            if(err) {
                res.status(500);
                console.log("errr 500")
            } else {
                if(!user)
                res.status(400).json({message:"user not found"});

                res.status(200).json({"user" : user})
            }
        })

    })
```

server.js

```
const express = require("express");

const path = require('path');

const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const passport = require("passport");


const app = express();
const users = require("./controllers/api/users")



app.use(

    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(express.static(`${__dirname}/client/build`));


// app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/client/build/index.html`)
// })
// app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/../', 'build', 'index.html'));
//  });

//DATA BASE CONFIGURATION

const dbkeys = require("./config/key").mongoURI;

mongoose.connect( 
    dbkeys, 
    {useNewUrlParser: true} )

        .then(()=> console.log("database connection successful"))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))

app.use(passport.initialize());
require("./config/passport")(passport);


app.use("/api/users", users);

// app.use("/api", users)


const port = 5000;

app.listen( port, () => console.log("server us up and running on port 5000!"))
```

Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ClassworkSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String,
    isDone: false
});

const OutcomesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    todo: String, 
    isDone: false,
    isApproved: false
})

const MeetupSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    time: Date,
    location: String,
    attended: false
})
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    date: {
      type: Date,
      default: Date.now
    },
    classwork:{type: [ClassworkSchema], default: []},
    outcomes: [OutcomesSchema],
    meetups: [MeetupSchema],
  });


  // const User = mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);
  // const Classwork = mongoose.model('Classwork', ClassworkSchema );

  // module.exports = {
  //   User : User ,
  //   // Classwork : Classwork 
  // }
  module.exports = mongoose.model("users", UserSchema);
```

Comment: Please return a message for every 400 error in the backend and check in which case the 400 error is returned.

Comment: I might know the solution to your problem, could you add the "User" collection Schema?

Comment: I added my Schema to the original post. and I am checking on those 400 error messages  on the backend

Comment: If it works on Postman, the problem probably isn't on server-side, can you post a most detailed message of the error ?  Open your console , go to Network tab, so finds the request then click on it, then go to the Response tab, what appears ?

Comment: @EduardoFellipe  I found the response in the network tab, it is in the controller code. it is the second 400 message error with `userId not valid`. Do have any idea why this is.

Comment: `this.props.match.params.userId` is wrong

Comment: @Evert how so I've used that in other projects and it has worked fine how is it causing a problem here?

Comment: @Wadaygo if it worked before, and now it doesn't _something_ is different. This property contains the _literal_ string `:userId`, and not a number. What you think that property is, it isn't. Might be a problem with whatever calls this component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the server side localhost endpoint in your GET request from the client side.

```
 getUser = () =>{
const userId = this.props.match.params.id;
   axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/users/${userId}`).then(res=>{
       const user = res.data;
       this.setState({
           user
       })
   }).catch((err)=> console.log(err))
}
```

You are requesting a response from the server side , so it is required to include the correct path to which the response should travel.

You will need to include this path in all of the requests you send from the client side to the server side. I recommend using a proxy in the client side package.json as below,

```
"proxy":"http://localhost:5000"
```

This will let you write your endpoint path as you have done in your GET request implementation.

For the CORS error,

Install CORS in your server side package.json as `npm install cors`

Then import CORS to your server.js as `const cors = require('cors');`

Then use CORS as middleware `app.use(cors());`

Comment: I refactored my code to this answer and now it gives me this error in the console. `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/users/:userId' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: Since you are communicating with 2 different domains you need to install CORS, I have edited the answer to solve the above problem as well

Comment: I added install and added cors to my server.js, but I believe it is a problem with `req.params` in the controller route where it gives the error message `userId not found` when I change the `req.params` to `req.params.id` it gives me this error `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'userId' of 'req.params.id' as it is undefined.`

Comment: Check the updated answer for the GET request, I have made some changes , it should be params.id and you need to pass the  Id to the URL as the answer I have provided

Comment: That helped but it still gives the 400 error with this response in the Network tab `{"message":"userId  not valid"}`  I 'm now sure that the problem is in the controller and has something to do with how I use `req.params` and `ObjectId.isValid()`

Comment: Why are you trying to destructor the id, just define the variable as a let variable ,   `let userId = req.params.id;`